# Ptr suffix in ROS messages

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to know if i could get an object of message X when I have an object of message XPtr. For example, if I have an object of type geometry_msgs::PosePtr, is it possible to get an object of type geometry_msgs::Pose? Furthermore, what is the difference between geometry_msgs::Pose* and geometry_msgs::PosePtr? Thanks a lot in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334163/ptr-suffix-in-ros-messages/) by [thanasis_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/39948/thanasis_t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2019-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You you can definitely make a concrete message type from a `<Message>Ptr` type. Because the original type is a pointer you'll need to copy the entire message to do this, fine for small geometry messages but it will have a performance penalty for larger point cloud or image message types. You can use the copy constructor to create a local concrete instance of a message which is the same as a given `<Message>Ptr` type. This is the same as if if was a regular C++ pointer.

```
void myFunction(geometry_msgs::PosePtr postMsg)
{
    geometry_msgs::Pose concretePose = *poseMsg;

    // ... do something with concretePose 
}
```

Regarding your second point the `geometry_msgs::PosePtr` is actually a `boost::shared_ptr<geometry_msgs::Pose>` not a simple C++ pointer. A Boost shared pointer is a smart pointer container that ensures memory will always deleted when no more references to the object exist. You can read more about [these here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm).

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thanasis_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/39948/thanasis_t/) on 2019-09-29**:
Yes your comment was very helpful. Thanks a lot.